# Is there any exsiting facial expression model libary?

Tags: unity

I'm making a project and it needs 10 different facial expression.

After some reasearch,it seems that the only way is to use the facial rig.

But the rig will not fit different 3D model.

So I just wondering that if there anything like mixamo but for faical expression.

Comment: "What library should I use for..." questions are generally not on-topic for this site, but "How can I solve this problem..." questions are on topic, and answers can suggest libraries if they're helpful to solving the problem. Can you **edit your question** to focus more on the problem you need to solve, rather than your search for a library to solve it?